# How to remove this warning: second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a function (see below) that is emitting the following warning:

> second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument

What does it means and how to remove it?

The function is as the following:

```
static int  ui_show_warning(GtkWindow *parent, const gchar *fmt, size_t size, ...)
    {
      GtkWidget *dialog = NULL;
      va_list args = NULL;
      int count = -1;
      char *msg = NULL;

      if((msg = malloc(size + 1)) == NULL)
        return -12;

      va_start(args, fmt);

      if((count = snprintf(msg, size, fmt, args)) < 0)
        goto outer;

      dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(parent,
                      GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                      GTK_MESSAGE_WARNING,
                      GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
                      "%s", msg);
      (void) gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));

      gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);

     outer: {
        if(args != NULL)
          va_end(args);

        if(msg != NULL)
          free(msg);

        return count;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It means what it says. You need to give it the last parameter before the ellipsis. You might find this helpful for truly explaining why: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4181/Variable-Argument-Functions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `size` instead of `fmt`:

```
va_start(args, size);
```

It is `size`, not `fmt`, that is the last parameter that has an explicit name (as opposed to vararg parameters, which have no names). You need to pass the last named parameter to `va_start` in order for it to figure out the address in memory at which the vararg parameters start.

Comment: I still confuse about the answer. what is size? I have a function like that: void function(int, const string& fmt, ...);, and when I use va_start, this warning is displayed. So what need I do?

Comment: @TrungNguyen His arg list is `parent, fmt, size`, and `...`. Last named parameter before `...` is `size`.

Comment: I have figured out the problem with my function. Because I used const string& fmt, when I pass fmt to va_start I need to convert to char* like fmt.c_str() => warning.

Comment: what if the function has no arguments at all? like `Constructor::call(...)`

Comment: @MDP Functions with no parameters cannot have variable length arguments.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument
> ```
>
> What does it means and how to remove it?

Your function has named parameters `parent`, `fmt` and `size`.  The C spec says you have to always pass the last named parameter to `va_start`, for compatibility with older compilers.  So you must pass `size`, not `fmt`.

(But with a modern compiler, it might work anyway)

Comment: What will a modern compiler do though in this case? E.g., will it use the parameter specified anyway, or intrinsically change it to be the last named one in the function signature?

Comment: A modern compiler will probably intrinsically change it to be the last named one in the function signature.

Modern compilers implement this as a built-in so they can optimize better.  E.g. the last named parameter may be passed in a register or even optimized out completely.

Older compilers knew that parameters were pushed onto the stack in order, so they implemented va_start etc as macros in the header file, without special compiler support.  In that case, they needed to start with the address of the last named parameter.

Comment: (But don't depend on that!  Pass the correct value!)

Comment: If so (intrinsic change), but the programmer meant exactly what they wrote, it will lead to a bug. We have cross-platform compilation where VS says nothing, but gcc on Linux warns about it. So that may lead to different behavior under different OSes.

Comment: Lets be clear: If you write code that calls va_start and pass something that is not the last named parameter, then YOUR CODE HAS A BUG.  A compiler is allowed to compile that as a call to _exit(), or as instructions that format your hard disk.  More likely, if you have an if{}else{} where the if{} branch does this, the compiler is allowed to assume that that branch never happens and remove the if statement, just leaving the code that was in else{}. It may happen to do what you want on one particular version of a compiler on one particular system, but a "bugfix" compiler release might change it

Comment: You are relying on "undefined behaviour".  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: Yes. The programmer that wrote it did not realize that until I showed them this topic here. So the bug is now fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a confusion here: most of people only deal with prinf-like functionsh which have format and varargs. and they think they have to pass parameter name which describes format. however va_start has nothing to do with any kind of printf like format. this is just a function which calculates offset on the stack where unnamed parameters start.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu20.04，Contrary to the answer with the most likes，
the code at the beginning,

```
void sprintf(char *str, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list list;
    int i, len;
    va_start(list, 2);
    ...
}
```

and then, the code as follows

```
void sprintf(char *str, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list list;
    int i, len;
    va_start(list, fmt);
    ...
}
```

Problem was sovled.

Comment: That was another issue. You did not even use a parameter name at all. Your solution is not contrary to the existing answer. Exactly as in the accepted answer you need to use the last parameter from the list.

Comment: @Gerhardh wow,I am so confused that the same code worked well on Deepin, but didn't work on Ubuntu20.04